# How to properly finish a python 3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, exit

In C++, the `main()` function is standardized to be of type `int`, and thus should `return(0)` with successful execution. Also, programs will typically print one line feed at the end to flush `stdout`, like so:

**MINIMAL, COMPLETE, VERIFIABLE EXAMPLE**

**hello_world.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;

    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

*hello, world*

Is there an equivalent way to properly exit a Python script? Does it make sense to also print a line feed, and then explicitly exit with code 0?

**hello_world.py**

```
import sys
print("hello, world")

print('\n')
sys.exit(0)
```

*hello, world*

Tyvm :^)

Comment: flushing will (generally) happen automatically as part of deconstructing stuff  - did you try what returncode a python program returns if you not explicitly sys.exit(0)? Why ask if you can try it out?

Comment: In my experience (both personally and what I have seen others do) you just let the python code end on its own (no `exit` statement). You should probably use a `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement though.  Python doesn't require (nor specify in PEP) that you end the program with a special line such as an `exit`.  Also for the record, by default `print` puts a `\n` at the end so you don't need to print again.

Comment: Printing an empty line "just in case" is a nuisance, not a good practice.

Comment: Also `print`s don't `flush` in python unless specifically told to via `flush=True`. Just another FYI.

Comment: I'm not sure if that fits in your question's scope, but as for *exiting gracefully*, a very common construct in Python is the `try/except` which helps you handle errors and terminate your program. Even better, is wrapping context managers with `with` statement which makes sure a program exits gracefully in case of errors within that block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A python script ends when there's no more code to run. The textbook hello world program is one line:

```
print("hello, world!")
```

Python's `print()` function is equivalent to other languages' `println()` function, in that it prints a newline by default. You can change this behavior with the optional `end` keyword argument:

```
print("Hello", end=" ")
print("World!")
```

And if you just want to print an extra line for whatever reason, you don't even have to go to the extra trouble of specifying it - you can just call `print()` with no arguments and it'll print a blank line.

Most python scripts you'll see will additionally have a feature like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello, world!")
```

This is essentially a filter to make sure that the current code is being run *as* a script, and that it wasn't just imported by some other file (`__name__` is a built-in variable that states the name by which the module was imported, or `"__main__"` if it was run directly from the command line and thus wasn't imported from anywhere).

By default, a python script will exit with the code `0`. You can use the built-in `exit()` (or `sys.exit()` if you want to be a bit more safe - see @cdarke's excellent comment below) if you want to exit with a different return code (e.g. if your script encounters an error and you want to exit gracefully). Otherwise, the standard practice is to just let the script end on its own.

Comment: So... how to properly finish a Python script? Note that I'm intentionally avoiding the words ``terminate``, ``exit``, and the like.

Comment: @kmiklas: with a blank line

Comment: Whoa... is this truth? I feel strangely unfulfilled by this answer.

Comment: @kmiklas PEP states there should be one blank line at the end of your file. That line is not needed but that is common formatting. Python doesn't require anything fancy to say "I am now done with my code", just stop typing :)

Comment: *You can use the built-in exit() function* - no.  There appears to be a built-in called `exit` which has the same behaviour as `sys.exit`, but appearances can be deceptive.  `exit` is not a built-in function but a `site.Quitter` callable object which raises a `SystemExit` exception.  The site module is usually automatically loaded on start-up, but can be supressed with the `-S` command-line option, in which case `exit` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @cdarke. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit, specifically "*They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.*"